# React Js :How does react route to different pages even though there is only one html file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

[image: In this image these is only one html file that declared]

1. How does react does this internally ?
2. How are routes complied into normal javascript ? (I have not seen any routing libraries in normal javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript can be used to manipulate the URL and your local page history without reloading the page, which is the main idea behind how React Router works (see [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)). Combine this with the fact that you can selectively show / hide content with JavaScript and you have React Router. For example:

js (with some jQuery syntactic sugar)

```
function toggle() {
    $('#blockOne').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('#blockOne').toggleClass('visible');

    $('#blockTwo').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('#blockTwo').toggleClass('visible');
}
```

css

```
.hidden { display: none }
.visible { display: block }
```

html

```
<div id="blockOne">First content</div>
<div id="blockTwo" class="hidden">Second content</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Clicking the button would cause the first and second block to toggle their visibility. Of course, there's a bit more complexity with React Router, but this is the basic idea. Browser history manipulation + showing / hiding content with JS.